# Watching sockets with Glib on Windows puts them in non-blocking mode

Tags: python, windows, pygtk, glib, gio

The following code does not work correctly on Windows (but does on Linux):

```
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setblocking(True)
    sock.connect(address)
    gobject.io_add_watch(
            sock.fileno(),
            gobject.IO_OUT | gobject.IO_ERR | gobject.IO_HUP,
            callback)
```

Snippets of comments in various places in the glib source, and other places mention that in Windows, sockets are put in non-blocking mode during polling. As a result the callback `self.outgoing_cb` is constantly called, and writing to the socket fails with this error message:

```
[Errno 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

Calling `sock.setblocking(True)` prior to writing does not seem to circumvent this. By lowering the priority of the polling, and ignoring the error message, it works as expected, but throws far to many events, and consumes a lot of CPU. Is there a way around this limitation in Windows?

**Update**

I might point out, that the whole point of polling for `POLLOUT` is that when you make the write call you won't get `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`. The strange error message that I'm getting, I believe would be the Windows equivalent of those 2 error codes. In other words, I'm getting `gobject.IO_OUT` events when the socket will not let me write successfully, **and** putting it into blocking mode still gives me this inappropriate error.

**Another update**

On Linux, where this works correctly, the socket is not switched to non-blocking mode, and I receive `IO_OUT`, when the socket will let me write without blocking, or throwing an error. It's this functionality I want to best emulate/restore under Windows.

**Further notes**

From `man poll`:

```
   poll()  performs a similar task to select(2): it waits for one of a set
   of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.
          POLLOUT
                 Writing now will not block.
```

From `man select`:

```
A file descriptor  is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corre‐
sponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.
```

Comment: Regarding what you've cited from the manpage: It will not block for a certain amount of bytes, correct.  HOWEVER...  you will still get EAGAIN at the very end of your successful operations.  And it doesn't tell you what that amount of bytes is.  So the proper reponse to one of these events is to successfully read or write as much as you can, then get EAGAIN (also known as EWOULDBLOCK) when you have exhausted that number.

Comment: @asveikau: EAGAIN only applies for nonblocking sockets. If select() returns that a blocking socket is ready to be written to, it will receive as many bytes as it can and return that number, immediately.

Comment: @Anacrolix I thought we were talking about write() here. If you select() on a blocking socket, and it told you it's time to write, then you write() more than can be immediately sent, it will block.  Further, in the read case, since you mentioned it... First of all I don't think what you wrote is true.. But supposing it is... How do you know the upper bound of what can be read? Just pass in a large buffer? That doesn't make sense. Better to read() in a loop and not be bounded by arbitrary sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a problem with doing non-blocking I/O?  It seems kind of strange to use polling loops if you're using blocking I/O.

When I write programs like this I tend to do the following:

- Buffer the bytes I want to send to the file descriptor.
- Only ask for `IO_OUT` (or the `poll()` equivalent, `POLLOUT`) events when said buffer is non-empty.
- When `poll()` (or equivalent) has signaled that you're ready to write, issue the write. If you get `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, remove the bytes you successfully wrote from the buffer and wait for the next time you get signaled.  If you successfully wrote the entire buffer, then stop asking for `POLLOUT` so you don't spuriously wake up.

(My guess is that the Win32 bindings are using [WSAEventSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741576%28VS.85%29.aspx) and `WaitForMultipleObjects()` to simulate `poll()`, but the result is the same...)

I'm not sure how your desired approach with blocking sockets would work.  You are "waking up" constantly because you asked to wake you up when you can write. You only want to specify that when you have data to write...  But then, when it wakes you up, the system won't really tell you *how much* data you can write without blocking, so that's a good reason to use non-blocking I/O.

Comment: yes, i guess the difference is that windows returns that the socket is writable, even if it isn't. this isn't my desired behaviour, as writing to it then fails, and then i immediately get teh same IO_OUT event again, failing again... etc.

Comment: that hasn't been my experience working with WSAEventSelect().  maybe there is something else you've omitted?  maybe more code would shed more light?

Comment: I've updated my question to point out an apparent misunderstanding around EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: Your answer is inaccurate regarding justification for using non-blocking I/O.

Comment: It's not inaccruate. It's a bad idea to use blocking I/O in a poll loop where multiple sockets are served by the same thread. The write notifaction tells you a write is possible, but it does not tell you excactly how many bytes can be written. This is what EAGAIN is for. If you issue a blocking write() where the number of bytes exceeds what you are actually able to write, you will hold up other sockets in your polling loop from being serviced. Try it. But you're right, don't listen to me, I only know what I'm talking about. :P

Comment: By the way, from a Google search, I think your issue is actually caused by a limitation of how the GLIB folks ported their polling stuff to Windows. I saw something saying they advocate doing your writes in response to a read event. Or something like this.

Comment: Yes, limitations in the Win32, or shortcomings, are the reasons for Glib not working the same way on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[GIO](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/index.html) contains [GSocket](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/GSocket.html), a "lowlevel network socket object" since 2.22. However this is yet to be ported to [pygobject on Windows](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygobject/).

Comment: After testing now that it has been ported to Windows, it seems GSocket makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps (I'm not proficient with the poll function or the MFC sockets and don't know the polling is a requirement of your program structure), so take this with a grain of salt:

But to avoid a blocking or EAGAIN on write, we use select, i.e. add the socket to the write set that is passed to select, and if select() comes back with rc=0 the socket will accept writes right away ...

The write loop we use in our app is (in pseudocode):

```
set_nonblocking.
count= 0.
do {
   FDSET writefds;
   add skt to writefds.
   call select with writefds and a reaonsable timeout.
   if (select fails with timeout) {
       die with some error;
   } 

   howmany= send(skt, buf+count, total-count).
   if (howmany>0) {
       count+= howmany.
   }
} while (howmany>0 && count<total);
```

Comment: @Nicholaz, this is what I'm trying to achieve. The `io_add_watch()` call should be the equivalent of a `select()` as you've described. In your example `howmany` is returning effectively returning `-1` for me.

Comment: Again. You cannot avoid properly handling EAGAIN with poll() nor select() nor WaitForMultipleObjects(). Even if poll() or select() says, there is some room in socket's output buffer, it doesn't say how much room. Which means you don't know how much you can write. That's why you usually don't use blocking IO with poll() or select() - the whole point is to avoid blocking. And with non-blocking IO you get EAGAIN when this internal socket buffer fills up. This is not an error. It's a correct usage.

Comment: @tomekszpakowicz: to quote `select()` from the manpage, (`poll()` and friends are very similar but more platform-specific): "A file descriptor  is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.". Please RTFM before you declare correct usage.

Comment: @Anacrolix: Sorry. It's been a long time since I last programmed this staff so I might be talking s**t. Good luck.

Comment: @Anacrolix -- Sorry, Tom is right.  poll() and select() tell you what you can do without blocking, but they do not tell you how many bytes.  Your citation of the manpage does not contradict this.

Comment: poll() is a replacement for the older select(). poll() offers higher granularity on the types of events to wait for, and it is not limited to FD_SETSIZE file descriptors, but otherwise there is not much difference between them. on unix, GLIB wraps poll() for its event loops. hence we _are_ talking about poll() semantics.  the Windows equivalent is WaitForMultipleObjects(). to use that with sockets you need WSAEventSelect() which offers poll()-like granularity on events that can be passed into WaitForMultipleObjects().

Comment: Argh! If select returns a file descriptor as being writable, it means you can write _at least one byte_. It _will not block_ regardless of how much you try to write, instead it will write as much as it can, and return how many bytes were written. This is always how write()/send() work, even without select being used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), which includes [support for GTK](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#auto11) (even on Windows) and will handle all the [various](http://itamarst.org/writings/win32sockets.html) error conditions that non-blocking sockets on Windows like to raise.